# how to remove clippings in konva?

Tags: konvajs

There's a lot of docs on how to set clipX, clipY, clipFunc, etc.

But there's no doc on how to remove clippings.

Is there any standard way of removing a clippings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set `undefined` or `null` properties:

```
layer.clipX(undefined);
layer.clipY(undefined);
layer.clipWidth(undefined);
layer.clipHeight(undefined);
layer.draw();
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/sz0dm02b/

Comment: thanks for the answer! do you think this should be on the konva docs?

Comment: @DevDoomari probably